# Ubuntu 13.10 Running Slowly Due to Xorg

Tags: drivers, xorg, 13.10

I'm having a bit of an issue with my new Ubuntu 13.10 installation. The user interface seems to be running *very* slowly. Upon investigation (running top in the command line), it appears that Xorg is running continuously and is consuming the bulk of my processing power.

Is there a reason why this is happening? Does this have something to do with my graphics driver? Below is my graphics driver options:

[image: Driver Options]

Is it best if I use the proprietary ones? I've had far too many bad experiences with changing drivers, so now as a result I'm overly cautious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it might be the problem because the source code of the AMD drivers is not accessible to Linux developers.

Install those drivers and it will solve your problem, and use that last option from the picture you sent.

Comment: That seemed to do it! Thanks! Just out of curiosity, why is the proprietary driver so much more effective? Is it simply because they write better drivers for their own specific hardware?

Comment: They only write drivers for their own specific hardware so that others won't use it that's why its called "PROPRIETORY"....